# [__NSDate timeIntervalSinceNow]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone

App crashed with the message when hitting rewind twice just to test app on iPhone device `[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceNow]: message sent to deallocated instance`

```
-(void)pauseTimer{
pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];

previousFireDate = [[timer fireDate] retain];

[timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}


-(void)dealloc
{
[audioPlayer release];
[pauseStart release];
[previousFireDate release];
[super dealloc];
}


  -(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {

if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
    [self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];
}else{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
    [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];

    if(isFirstTime == YES)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];
        isFirstTime  = NO;
    }
   } 
   }


 -(void)rewind:(id)sender{
[timer invalidate];
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
MainViewController *viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view]; 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[self playpauseAction:_playButton];
}
```

when hitting rewind button again and purposely to test app on iphone device app crashes and gives message **[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceNow]: message sent to deallocated instance**

Any ideas what is wrong.

Appreciate help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there places in your code that you call `timeIntervalSinceNow` (not `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow`)?

Comment: -(void)resumeTimer{
    float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
    
    [timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
}

Comment: OK, so `pauseStart` is probably the problem...how is it defined?  ...and are there other places where it's being released?

Comment: in the m file of mainviewcontroller defined it  NSDate *pauseStart, *previousFireDate; releasing it in only dealloc method

Comment: Hmmm.  That suggests you'll have a memory leak if you call `pauseTimer` twice before this object is deallocated...but that doesn't explain your problem.  Sorry.

Comment: Was just going to write the same =)

Comment: At this point, if it was my project, I'd run it with Instruments to check for zombies and look at the retain/release history of whatever it indicated was the deallocated instance.

Comment: i have enabled the zombies on in diagnostics it is not telling me anything. Is there anything needs to do besides enabling zombies in diagnostics

Comment: When you find a zombie in Instruments (a.k.a. Product->Profile), it shows an address with a small arrow beside it.  Clicking that arrow shows the history of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Removed

```
 [pauseStart release];
  [previousFireDate release];
```

from the dealloc method.

That solved my problem.

Comment: I think you'll find you are just hiding one issue and creating another, namely a memory leak.

Comment: I guess you are right in Instruments getting the memory leak for NSDate

Comment: Responsible frames for NSDate leak is resume Timer and pauseTimer. How can i fix this. If you can be of any help. Will appreciate so much.